# No puedo comprobar si directorio de linux existe con SAS

Tags: sas

Me gustaría encontrar la función equivalente en Linux a:

```
filename filerefpipe "ls -lr /tmp" Lrecl=200;
```

En macro variable:

```
%let rc = %sysfunc(filename(fileref,ls -lr /tmp));
```

Y que si el directorio existe `rc` sea igual a 1.

Un saludo

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Answer (score 0):

SAS te permite verificar si un directorio existe sin necesidad de usar unnamed pipes, de esta manera:

```
%let rc = %sysfunc(fexist("/tmp"));
```

Generalmente, la ejecución de comandos de sistema operativo desde SAS se considera una vulnerabilidad de seguridad, por lo que esta funcionalidad es deshabilitada. Por ello, se recomienda usar las funciones propias de SAS.